# asp.net:How to place columns from DB inbetween Template Fields of GridView

Tags: mysql, asp.net, gridview

Hello i want gridview which should be like

```
|Sl No|Std No|Student Name|Total Amount|Paid Amount|Unpaid Amount|Action|
```

Here I am setting `Sl No` ,`Unpaid Amount` , and `Action` Columns by Template Field.And Other i am directly getting from mysql DB and binding to gridview. But the columns from DB are apending to end of those 3 TemplateFields.And i cant use BoundFields for those `4 Fields` from DB.

*MY CODE IS LIKE THIS*

```
<div class="GridviewDiv">
                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvDetails" AllowPaging="false" AutoGenerateColumns="true" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound1">
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerstyle" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SlNo">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
                                <asp:Label ID="serialID" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <%-- HERE I WANT THOSE COLUMNS FROM DATABASE--%>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unpaid Amount">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="UnpaidText" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Take Fee">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="TakeFeeCash" runat="server" BackColor="#2C6AA0" BorderColor="#2C6AA0" align="right"
                                    BorderStyle="Ridge" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" OnClick="FeeCashButton_click"
                                    Text="Take Fee" CommandName="Select" />

                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

What i am getting is like this
**IMAGE:**

[image]

How to set my columns like above format?

Please Help.

Comment: Edit your question and add at least the markup for the `GridView` to the question. Otherwise we have to guess what it looks like.

Comment: Why not use `TemplateField` for all columns? Then you can decide the order easily.

Comment: because i am using this gridview for two different queries based on user selection.As in boundfield we need to assign one column to perticular column of DB,so  i cant use boundfields.

Comment: This *can* sort of be done by manipulating the `GridView` and it's rows in the `OnDataBound` and `OnItemDataBound` event. But it will difficult to setup so that it works in different `postback` scenarios and generally speaking it will be a nightmare to maintain, especially for someone who didn't implement it to start with. Best thing to do here is to simply create two separate grids for the different cases.